# Magento 2: How to add block inside admin view order (information tab)?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides, sales-order, view

I'm trying to add a custom block inside the Order view information on admin.
And it's being so weird. I can do it inside other tabs but on Information doesn't work.

Looking at the original layout, `sales_order_view.xml`:

```
(...)
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="order/view/tab/info.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Messages" name="order_messages"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="order/view/info.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="order/view/items.phtml">
(...)
        </block>

        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">order_tab_info</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments" name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_shipments</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_shipment.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions" name="sales_transactions.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_transactions.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
(...)
```

What I need is to insert a block at the end of the block `order_tab_info`

So my layout override is:

`sales_order_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info">
            <block class="Gsp\OrderCrm\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom"
                   template="order/view/custom.phtml"
                   after="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And this is actually doing **nothing**

What is funny is, if I change the referenceBlock for:

`sales_order_invoice.grid.container`

`sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container`

`sales_order_shipment.grid.container`

`sales_transactions.grid.container`

**works**

But I need this on the Information tab!

Why the information tab doesn't follow the same nomenclature? it should be like: `sales_order.grid.container` but the log says doesn't exist.

Also couldn't do it on the comments history, don't know the name it's `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History` this is not the layout block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like this answer but it's the only way I know to move on because I don't even know how to learn to do these things. How did you learn? this is so frustrating.

My **temporary** solution overrides the entire template that prints the info order tab:

`sales_order_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info" template="Gsp_OrderCrm::order/view/tab/info.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy paste

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml
```

into

```
app\code\Gsp\OrderCrm\view\adminhtml\templates\order\view\tab\info.phtml
```

And add my custom section in the end.

**Really I have to do that?**

I'm only extending the template, and I have to copy paste all the original template?